# Splitting dataframe that has variable number of parameters into tuple

Tags: python

I have an ansible playbook that runs the command

```
#show int status
```

on a network device. I'm trying to count the number of free ports available for use. It returns this output

```
[u'Et2        description1       notconnect   in Po23       full    10G Not Present ']
[u'Et3        description2       notconnect   1152          full    10G Not Present ']
[u'Et4        other desc         notconnect   1             full    10G Not Present ']
[u'Et5                           notconnect   1             full    10G Not Present ']
```

I'm only interested in the first 3 columns. The network device does not support json formatting so I can't run

```
#show int status | json
```

I'd like to have 3 lists that I can then zip and use as I already do for other network devices that support json; the lists looking like

```
list1 = ['Et2', 'Et3', 'Et4', 'Et5']
list2 = ['description1', 'description2', '', '']
list3 = ['notconnect','notconnect', 'notconnect', 'notconnect']
```

But because of the description field sometimes being empty, I can't work out a good *.split()* for accurately return the  lists as *.split[1]* will sometimes have a description and sometimes be 'notconnect' if I split by spacing. Is there a good way of doing this?

Comment: Did you try using regular expressions ?

Comment: @Arnaud regex is definitely a weak point for me unfortunately

Comment: Is the notconnect common and always present or can it be an other value in this field? and if so, which value (connect I assume?).

Comment: @Mathieu connected, notconnected, disabled, err-disabled are the potential statuses

Comment: If you have a quite precise expectation of all potential statuses then we could figure out a regex I guess. Two first columns are "Et*" and "description*", always ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is probably the best solution, but anyway, if you don't want to use it, I see 2 solutions.

First: use the fact that the formatting seems quite consistent between lines, and that each new item starts at the same point in the line.

```
a = 'Et3        description2       notconnect   1152          full    10G Not Present '
b = 'Et4                           notconnect   1             full    10G Not Present '
L = [a, b]

list1, list2, list3 = [], [], []

for elt in L:
    list1.append(elt[0:11].strip(" "))
    list2.append(elt[11:30].strip(" "))
    list3.append(elt[30:43].strip(" "))


# Output:
list1
Out[8]: ['Et3', 'Et4']

list2
Out[9]: ['description2', '']

list3
Out[10]: ['notconnect', 'notconnect']
```

Second, use `if / elif "string" in elt:` statements and built rules to parse your data.

EDIT with rstrip():

```
a = 'Et3        description2       notconnect   1152          full    10G Not Present '
b = 'Et4        other desc         notconnect   1             full    10G Not Present '
L = [a, b]

list1, list2, list3 = [], [], []

for elt in L:
    list1.append(elt[0:11].rstrip(" "))
    list2.append(elt[11:30].rstrip(" "))
    list3.append(elt[30:43].rstrip(" "))

# Output
list1
Out[2]: ['Et3', 'Et4']

list2
Out[3]: ['description2', 'other desc']

list3
Out[4]: ['notconnect', 'notconnect']
```

Comment: Updated the question apologies, hadn't realised some descriptions have spaces in the string

Comment: Just replace strip(" ") by rstrip(" ") and it works. Point is that the elt you want to parse are starting at the same ID. We don't care at which they end, and remove only the space at the end.